# Is there a way to specify which chunk to start at with Pandas read_sql_query?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large amount of data on a database. I'm using `pandas.read_sql_query` with a `chunksize` to be able to get this data in chunks to avoid memory issues. With each of these chunks I run a process with it, this process runs at a rate of roughly 5 chunks per minute. The whole process will take hours to complete and sometimes an issue occurs that drops my connection. I need to be able to restart the process if this happens.

Currently I have

```
j = 0
while True:
    try:
        for i,chunked_data in enumerate(pd.read_sql_query (dataQuery, connection_source, chunksize=100)):
            if i < j: 
                continue
            print(f"{i}/28660")
            j = i
            ... do stuff
        break
    except:
        print("Exception")
        connection_source = db.GetConnection()
        eng = db.GetSQLAlchemyEngine("datasets")
```

This still sends a request for data each time while it tries to get back to the dropped point. Is there a way to let pandas know that I would like to start at chunk `j`?

Note: Each chunk can be treated as a read only. I do not modify it requiring the table to be updated.

Comment: so you have 28660 queries to run? You're running the same query 28660 times? If the query crashes, the data would be incomplete, therefore you would need to run the whole query again.

Comment: The query is not the long part. The post processing of the data returned by the query is the time consuming process. The error happens when I try to get another chunk and it says sorry the connection is no longer available.

Comment: I think you need to make your question a bit clearer. Your if statement doesn't really make sense in the context of things.

Comment: @mrpbennett I have updated the question, does it make a little more sense?

Comment: Kinda, I think you may need to append something to a list. You could append each chunk to a list after it's done. IF the job stops you could compare what whats in the list to the current chunk and if its in the list to skip it. That way I think you might be able to carry on where you left off?